# How to implement soundcloud header layout for profile

Tags: android

[image: title here]

how to implement  above layout using mostly the fact that the toolbar doesn't move while the image under it slide up and down, i want achieve the same effect ,am currently implementing using the new cordinatorlayout and collapsing toolbar and Relative layout containing and image

[image: title here]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.madiba.listmulti.TabbedActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        app:titleEnabled="false"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">



            <RelativeLayout
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/banner"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:src="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="180dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Follow"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/main_title"
                    android:layout_below="@id/banner"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Flume Concert"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_below="@id/main_title"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:text="12 event | "
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:text="4 members "
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>


            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"

                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Flume Concert"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <!--</LinearLayout>-->


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/black"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```